# Textmate key binding for Caret (^)

Tags: textmate

When I type the caret symbol (^) in Textmate I get '&ldquo';&rdquo'.
I've not found any reference in their help or via search as to how I can override or modify this key binding.  This is not a universal key binding for my laptop as I get the caret symbol as expected in all other apps.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you working in? HTML? XML? Are you using the english keyboard?

Go to `Bundles -> Select Bundle Item...` and from the magnifying glass drop-down select `Key Equivalent` and type the caret. This will tell you if any bundle items are bound to the caret.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem... (The key was being overridden in every language.)  A bundle named 'Pragmatic' had an 'HTML curly quotes' binding to the caret key.  I deleted the bundle and all is well.